# sharing email from non-microsoft emails to developer tenant and vice-versa

Tags: office365

We are having an issue with sharing Excel sheets (online Office 365, not local files) from a non-Microsoft account to our dev tenant account and vice-versa.   We are able to have any microsoft account share with our dev tenant account and vice-versa, but not with a non-microsoft account.   For example, sharing from xyz@hotmail.com to abc@troparesheets.com (our Microsoft tenant troparesheets.onmicrosoft.com) works fine. We can also share from abc@troparesheets.com back to xyz@hotmail.com.   We get email notifications in both cases.   However, if we have someone that uses a non-Microsoft account with their Office 365 subscription - say  jkl@tropare.com - and he shares a spreadsheet with abc@troparesheets.com (our dev tenant), we never get a notification of the share, nor does it show up in 'shared documents'.   Also, if we share from abc@troparesheets.com to jkl@tropare.com - he does not get the invitation.   If we share from jkl@tropare.com to mno@tropare.com - or vice versa - both accounts get notifications.  So, the problem is sharing into and out of our dev tenant with a non-Microsoft account.   Is that a restriction on the dev-tenant/E5 or is there some other issue?  Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I believe the question is pretty specific and points out precisely the issue we are having sharing a spreadsheet from a non-microsoft account to a dev tenant account and vice versa does not generate an email.

Comment: This ended up being a restriction on Microsoft's dev-tenant account.  Moving to a production account solves the problem.  My understanding is that nefarious folks used the dev-tenants to spam people - thus the restriction.